# API ExchangeWebService v2.2 error on Win2012 Server R2

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm creating a software that will parse an email then reply to sender whether email is valid or not.

In my development machine (Win8.1), everything is fine then I created an exe to test it in our server running on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

To my surprise, it threw an error.

I tried changing the ff but nothing seems to work:

```
service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010)
service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1)
service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2)
```

Does this mean EWS is not compatible with Win2012 Server R2?

TIA

****UPDATE****
Since Im only having the  error when ran in the server, Im suspecting that my error is coming from this code:

```
    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(
       WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
       new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false)),
       new ItemView(int.MaxValue));
```

How I initialize EWS:

```
ExchangeService service;
            service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010)
            {
                Credentials = new WebCredentials(EmailAddress, EmailPassword, Domain),
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                TraceEnabled = true,
                Url = new Uri(EmailHostServerURL)
            };
```

The error:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceVersionException: Exchange Server doesn't support the requested version.
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ProcessWebException(WebException webException)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems[TItem](IEnumerable`1 parentFolderIds, SearchFilter searchFilter, String queryString, ViewBase view, Grouping groupBy, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandlingMode)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems(FolderId parentFolderId, SearchFilter searchFilter, ViewBase view)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName parentFolderName, SearchFilter searchFilter, ViewBase view)
```

**UPDATE 2**

After knowing that our exchange is Exchange 2010, I changed it to that. Now this is my error...

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The target principal name is incorrect
   at System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(Byte[] incomingBlob, Boolean throwOnError, SecurityStatus& statusCode)
   at System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(String incomingBlob)
   at System.Net.NegotiateClient.DoAuthenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate)
   at System.Net.NegotiateClient.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials)
   at System.Net.AuthenticationManager.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials)
   at System.Net.AuthenticationState.AttemptAuthenticate(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, ICredentials authInfo)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmitForAuth()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmit(Exception& e, Boolean& disableUpload)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.Emit(HttpWebRequest& request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(HttpWebRequest& request)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(HttpWebRequest& request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.InternalExecute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems[TItem](IEnumerable`1 parentFolderIds, SearchFilter searchFilter, String queryString, ViewBase view, Grouping groupBy, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandlingMode)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems(FolderId parentFolderId, SearchFilter searchFilter, ItemView view)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName parentFolderName, SearchFilter searchFilter, ItemView view)
```

**Question 2:**

While searching for an answer, I saw this [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rmilne/archive/2013/09/17/exchange-support-for-windows-server-2012-r2.aspx).
Does that mean no matter what I do, it will never work in Win2012 Server R2?

Comment: You need to look at the ExchangeVersion of the server your trying to access I would say given the error your trying to access an Exchange 2007 server so I would suggest you try using ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1. Also if you look at the response in the Trace that will contain the Schema version you should be using.

Comment: @GlenScales - Hi and thanks! I tried using Exchange2010 since they told me our exchange is 2010. Im still getting errors. Will update the question.

Comment: *`(401) Unauthorized. ---> ... The target principal name is incorrect`*

Comment: @Abhitalks - I know this is weird but I don't have that error when I'm running it on Win8.1 and Win7 (I installed a VM running in Win7 x64). But when I ran my exe in Win2012 Server R2, error shows... Why...?

Comment: Are you logged into the server as the same user that you are using on your development machine? I can assure you that logging into Exchange 2010 SP1 and higher works from every Windows server between 2008 and 2012 R2.

Comment: I had this same sort of issue, created an empty test proj and Exc13sp1 worked fine then I created a proj based off an vs angular 2 template proj we had and all of a sudden Exc10sp1 is the highest it will allow. I'm on a intranet domain and nothing has changed from morning to evening when I moved between projects so it's very strange.

Comment: Yes, it is really strange unless we don't know something. We might need to do something to make it work. I dunno... We (our team) decided to scrap this project coz we can't trace the problem. Yes, I was using the same username password in our Win2012 server R2.